# Tracking down issue with clojure implementation of Bron-Kerbosch non-pivot and pivoting algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, clojure, set

I am having issues tracking down an issue in my Clojure implementation of the [Bron-Kerbosch non-pivoting and pivoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) algorithms.

Here is the Bron-Kerbosch without pivoting (BK)
[image]

Here is the BK with pivoting (BKP)

[image]

I have managed, with some help from SO, to get the BK without pivoting to work. I have verified through quite a few sanity tests/graphs that it finds the correct set of maximal cliques.

My issue lies in the BK with pivoting algorithm. I am not quite sure how I can determine where the issue lies, and I have to assume that it is an issue with how I have implemented it.

Here is a SSCCE of the issue with the necessary functions http://pastebin.com/wm7dxvc8. Below are my implementations of the BK and BKP algorithms.

```
; Bron-Kerbosch with no pivot
(defn BK [r p x graph]
  (if (and (empty? p) (empty? x))
    [(set r)]
    (loop [p p, x x, cliques []]
      (if (empty? p)
        cliques
        (let [v (first p)
              nv (graph v)
              cliques (into cliques
                            (BK (into r (list v))
                                (filter nv p)
                                (filter nv x)
                                graph))
              p (rest p)
              x (into x (list v))]
          (recur p x cliques))))))

; Bron-Kerbosch with pivoting
(defn BKP [r p x graph]
  (if (and (empty? p) (empty? x))
    [(set r)]
    (let [u (first (into p x))
          nu (graph u)
          pnu (remove #(some (partial = %) nu) p)]
      (loop [p p, pnu pnu, x x, cliques []]
        (if (empty? pnu)
          cliques
          (let [v (first pnu)
                nv (graph v)
                cliques (into cliques
                              (BKP (into r (list v))
                                   (filter nv p)
                                   (filter nv x)
                                   graph))
                p (rest p)
                x (into x (list v))]
            (recur p (rest pnu) x cliques)))))))
```

Most of the time with small simple random graph both algorithms work to find the correct maximal clique set.

```
fptests.core> (testallbk (random-graph 5 6))
Starting test...
Timing evaluation of graph with BK :"Elapsed time: 0.098467 msecs"
Timing evaluation of graph with BKP:"Elapsed time: 0.144646 msecs"
BK  cliques count: 3  Largest:  3
   Cliques:  [#{0 4} #{1 4} #{1 3 2}]
BKP cliques count: 3  Largest:  3
   Cliques:  [#{0 4} #{1 4} #{1 3 2}]
```

Though sometimes, about 10%, the BKP algorithm manages to find more cliques than the BK algorithm. Almost all of the times that BKP has an error it reports two of the same clique

```
fptests.core> (testallbk (random-graph 5 6))
Starting test...
Timing evaluation of graph with BK :"Elapsed time: 0.102083 msecs"
Timing evaluation of graph with BKP:"Elapsed time: 0.097479 msecs"
BK  cliques count: 2  Largest:  3
   Cliques:  [#{0 1 4} #{0 3 2}]
BKP cliques count: 3  Largest:  3
   Cliques:  [#{0 1 4} #{0 3 2} #{0 3 2}]
```

But there are also instances where it reports all but one of the correct cliques, seemingly "cutting" off one of them

```
fptests.core> (testallbk (random-graph 5 6))
Starting test...
Timing evaluation of graph with BK :"Elapsed time: 0.076546 msecs"
Timing evaluation of graph with BKP:"Elapsed time: 0.079762 msecs"
BK  cliques count: 4  Largest:  2
   Cliques:  [#{0 1} #{0 3} #{1 2} #{4 3}]
BKP cliques count: 4  Largest:  2
   Cliques:  [#{0 1} #{0 3} #{4 3} #{2}]
```

When much larger random graphs are used the BKP algorithm sometimes manages to find less or more cliques than BK

```
fptests.core> (testallbk (random-graph 500 600))
Starting test...
Timing evaluation of graph with BK :"Elapsed time: 113.128014 msecs"
Timing evaluation of graph with BKP:"Elapsed time: 166.300653 msecs"
BK  cliques count: 631  Largest:  3
BKP cliques count: 629  Largest:  3
fptests.core> (testallbk (random-graph 500 600))
Starting test...
Timing evaluation of graph with BK :"Elapsed time: 109.454454 msecs"
Timing evaluation of graph with BKP:"Elapsed time: 166.39116 msecs"
BK  cliques count: 641  Largest:  3
BKP cliques count: 642  Largest:  3
```

Seeing that the number of cliques is never very far off from one another I would assume at some point in the BKP algorithm my implementation of set union, difference, and removing values from a set has some edge cases that are not accounted for.

Though, my limited knowledge of Clojure thus far has prevented me from further analyzing where the issue might lie. Seeing that the BK algorithm works for graphs of any size and that the `loop` statements in both the BK and BKP algorithms are the same. I think that the issue lies in the choosing of the pivot and the calculation of `u`, `nu`, and `pnu`. But again, with my knowledge it all seems correct to me.

Can anyone more knowledgeable track down my issue or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using the set operations in the `clojure.set` namespace?

Comment: I have been working on another implementation using them, I originally was not because of some bad choices with lists early on. After some refactoring and design changes I ended up with this implementation which I wanted to get working properly so that the issues did not propagate to another implementation.

Comment: I guess my first issue with using sets is that `first` and `rest` return lists (`(0 1 2)`) and not sets (`#{0 1 2}`) which are not allowed as input to `clojure.set/difference` for use in the recursive calls. Also `clojure.set/difference` seemingly will not return the proper result for `(clojure.set/difference p nv)`. Those issues are discussed in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737830/proper-use-of-sets-in-clojure-bron-kerbosch-implementation. // Though this question above is still my main issue overall...