# Proper use of sets in Clojure Bron-Kerbosch implementation

Tags: clojure

I am currently trying to use sets and the `clojure.set` namespace properly and effectively in my Clojure implementation of the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm and having difficulties.

I am trying to refactor my current implementation

```
(defn BK [r p x graph]
  (if (and (empty? p) (empty? x))
    [(set r)]
    (loop [p p, x x, cliques []]
      (if (empty? p)
        cliques
        (let [v (first p)
              nv (graph v)
              cliques (into cliques
                            (BK (into r (list v))
                                (filter nv p)
                                (filter nv x)
                                graph))
              p (rest p)
              x (into x (list v))]
          (recur p x cliques))))))
```

Into something that uses the `clojure.set` namespace as such

```
(defn BK3 [r p x graph]
  (if (and (empty? p) (empty? x))
    [(set r)]
    (loop [p p, x x, cliques []]
      (if (empty? p)
        cliques
        (let [v (first p)
              nv (graph v)
              cliques (into cliques
                            (BK3 (clojure.set/union (set (list v)) r)
                                 (clojure.set/difference p nv)
                                 (clojure.set/difference x nv)
                                 graph))
              p (rest p)
              x (clojure.set/union (set (list v)) x)]
          (recur p x cliques))))))

(defn get-BK3 [graph]
  (BK3 (set '()) (set (doall (range (count graph)))) (set '()) graph))
```

Though this current implementation causes a StackOverflow. Here is a short SSCCE with all of the necessary code to run evaluate the functions http://pastebin.com/PVxJidGB.

If I place a `prn` form before the `(if (empty? p))` in the function I can see that the set `p` is changed once and never again, also that the set `x` is never added to. The following is printed and repeats until a stack overflow occurs.

```
finalproject.core> (get-BK3 (random-graph 10 20))
"P: " #{0 7 1 4 6 3 2 9 5 8} " X: " #{}
-----------------
"P: " #{0 7 4 6 3 2 9 8} " X: " #{}
-----------------
"P: " #{0 7 4 6 3 2 9 8} " X: " #{}
-----------------
"P: " #{0 7 4 6 3 2 9 8} " X: " #{}
-----------------
....
```

This must mean that at each recursive call to `BK3` the set `p` does not have the set `nv` removed from it? Though reviewing the `clojure.set/difference` [help page](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/difference) it should be doing just that? Did I read the page wrong or have some typo that is causing the stack overflow?

That is my first issue that I don't understand. My next issue is that `first` and `rest` do not return sets (`#{0 1 2}`) rather lists (`(0 1 2)`). Which if a list is passed to any of the `clojure.set` functions errors are thrown. Are there any alternatives to `first` and `rest` that return sets?

EDIT: Here is the pseudo-code implementation from Wikipedia with the proper set notion symbols. I guess my interpretation of the symbols might possibly be incorrect?

[image]

Comment: when you are asking for `first` from a set, do you expect some ordering like smallest number being given ? or any thing. i think as such set do not have any order. you need to use `sorted-set` for ordering.

Comment: I had the same suspicion when I implemented the first algorithm above, but after tests against other working implementations using lists more heavily (that had been verified by hand to work properly) the order of how the elements are removed from `p` does not matter to the algorithm.

Comment: when you talk about `set/difference` do you mean : `(difference p v)` should change p ? otherwise what does : `the set p does not have the set nv removed from it` this mean ?

Comment: If `p` equals `#{0 1 2 3 4}` and `nv` equals `#{3 4 5 6}` then I would want/assume that `clojure.set/difference` returns `#{0 1 2}`. // I will make an edit shortly to be more clear by relating it to the algorithm pseudo-code from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered by @michat, in the wikipedia formula the recursive call is with set *intersection* and not set *difference*, which are not the same. In mathematics, the matching function for `clojure.set/difference` is [set complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)).

For your question on `first` and `rest` with `set`, you can use `first`, that will yield an element which is not necessary the next in order (but it doesn't matter in the algo) and `disj` to remove the selected element from the set.

Note you can simplify `(set '())` by `#{}`.

Following is a working version with `clojure.set`, with a very quick test/bench that shows some performance improvement with the `set` version:

```
(require '[clojure.set :as s])

(defn BK4 [r p x graph]
  (if (and (empty? p) (empty? x))
    [r] ;; r is already a set
    (loop [p p, x x, cliques []]
      (if (empty? p)
        cliques
        (let [v (first p) ;; p is a set, first is not necessary the next in sequence
              nv (graph v) ;; take v-th set from graph
              cliques (concat cliques
                            (BK4 (conj r v) ;; add v to the set r
                                 (s/intersection p nv)
                                 (s/intersection x nv)
                                 graph))]
          (recur (disj p v) (conj x v) cliques))))))

(defn get-BK4 [graph]
  (BK4 #{} (set (range (count graph))) #{} graph))
```

Test:

```
(let [graph (doall (random-graph 1000 1000))
      bk (time (get-BK graph))
      bk4 (time (get-BK4 graph))]
  (if (= bk bk4)
    (println "Seems ok")
    (println "ko")))
```

Prints (on a MBP 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7)

> "Elapsed time: 243.533768 msecs"
>   "Elapsed time: 19.228952 msecs"
>   Seems ok

Answer (score 1):

1. The recursive call in the pseudocode version of this algorithm from Wikipedia uses set intersection, not set difference. You can use `clojure.set/intersection` to compute the intersection of two persistent sets.
2. Set difference is used on the second line of the body of the *for each* loop. In your code, the corresponding expression is `(rest p)`, but this generates a seq of all elements of `p` except `(first p)`, not a set. You'll want to use `(disj p (first p))` instead (or I suppose `(disj p v)`, using the previously introduced local).
3. `set/union` and `into` are both overkill for adding a single element to a set – use `conj` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having StackOverflow, then conceptually this can happen in your code:

```
(clojure.set/difference #{1,2,3,4,5} #{4})
#{1 3 2 5}
user> (clojure.set/difference #{1,2,3,5} #{4})
#{1 3 2 5}
```

where `p` is `#{1 2 3 4 5}` and `nv` is `#{4}`.

In recursion, p becomes `#{1 3 2 5}` and then again you get same `v` (because you do not have self loops and hence 4 was not `v` earlier..) and hence same `nv` `#{4}`

i.e. first of two sets are same..

```
user> (first #{1 2 3 4 5})
1
user> (first #{ 1 2 3 5})
1
```

and again same recursion.. and stackoverflow..